# What is the minimum time slot for an Azure function wrt calculating costs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

What is the minimum time slot for an Azure function wrt calculating costs

The online calculator has a de minimus of 1 second, so is any run at least one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum time slot is 100ms, so the calculation is performed on the sub-second consumption amount (execution duration).

Unfortunately, the pricing calculator is currently limited to whole seconds, but I have passed this feedback on to the team that owns it so this limitation can be addressed.

Comment: the formula as well, should be GB-ms

Comment: The unit is correct. The charged unit is GB/s, with consumption calculated on 100 ms increments.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Thanks for the response. Is there someway to get the current GB/s for a function? ... we are looking at a single function that will be called a LOT, like starting at 10 million/day, so the cost could become a big factor.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128329/how-can-i-programmatically-access-azure-functions-usage-metrics

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Got that working ... you don't happen to have an easy way to sum up all the "total" values ??